# Swift IBOutlets are nil in awakeFromNib (xcode 6.1.1 osx 10.10.1)

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsviewcontroller

I have a NSViewController (I'm using a storyboard) with one iboutlet connected to a NSOutlineView (yes, I have made absolutely shure that it really is connected), but when I try to reference it in awakeFromNib, the outlet is still nil although they should be guaranteed to be connected in awakeFromNib. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: how about using `viewDidLoad` instead?

Comment: In viewDidLoad the outlet is set and I can reference it there. As the documentation for awakeFromNib states that all outlets are guaranteed to be set when awakeFromNib is called, this seem to be a swift bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple documentation says that the lifecycle of a `NSViewController` starts with `viewDidLoad`, so you should do your stuff there. 
[image]